# Responsive Bootstrap Cards

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to figure out why the cards I have at [www.dystopia.design](http://www.dystopia.design) aren't stacking at small break points. On smaller screens the three cards should be in a single column.

Comment: they do when width is `<= 575px`

Comment: I have checked at present it is ok. but as per your requirement you able to change using your CSS media query width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add meta viewport  viewport is most impotent for media query effect. 
So never forgot this tag for responsive website

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just add "mb-5" class for fixed it
[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding to this! I added the mb-5 class, but saw no change. Maybe my question isn't clear enough. When I simulate this on mobile devices, the cards remain in a row rather than stacked in a column. I'm not sure why this is, as I think I have the cards coded to stack responsively on top of eachother rather than have this behavior.

https://image.ibb.co/eeKjre/Screen_Shot_2018_09_17_at_10_44_35_AM.png

Comment: Add meta viewport after your head tag
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
and then after check

Comment: I have checked viewport in missing in your webpage source code